# Finding the right worm gear for a wormscrew that didn't come with technical specs

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears

I bought a CNC linear rail guide slide from ebay([seen here](https://www.ebay.com/itm/202481581216)). I'm trying to find a proper worm gear to mate with the wormscrew. There is no technical specification that came with the kit however on the wormscrew. I've manually measured the pitch of the wormscrew to be 2mm(12.7 threads per inch).

I'm looking at [this site's](http://shop.sdp-si.com/catalog/?cid=p390) catalog, but I'm just not sure what minimum measurements of the wormscrew I need in order to find a proper gear that fits. I just need to keep track of the number of turns the gear makes. I don't think I really care about the gear's quality class, gear ratio, bore/hub config. I just need it to fit the worm. Am I correct to assume the module(pitch) of the gear also needs to be 2mm? Do the pressure angle, lead angle, and number of teeth affect the fitting of the gear onto the worm?

I've seen suggestions online that I should just take the kit to grainger or mcmaster and ask for a proper gear that fits, but I'm not near either of those places.

Comment: So does the supplier you purchased from sell the correct gear? Did you check before purchase?

Comment: @solar-mike no the ebay supplier doesn't sell the gear, I did send them a message. The right thing to do would have been to check first like you said, but I didn't. So now I have to try to find a matching gear myself.